# Why am I obtaining these error related to methot that "doesn't exist" in my code?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, rxjs

I am not so into Angular and RxJS and, after some refactoring, I am finding the following problem with this service class:

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { finalize, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { AngularFireStorage } from '@angular/fire/storage';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {

  private eventAuthError = new BehaviorSubject<string>("");
  eventAuthError$ = this.eventAuthError.asObservable();

  newUser: any;

  downloadURL: Observable<string>;
  fb;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router,
    private storage: AngularFireStorage
    ){ }

    getUserState() {
      return this.afAuth.authState;
    }

    login( email: string, password: string) {
      this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .catch(error => {
      this.eventAuthError.next(error);
    })
    .then(userCredential => {
      if(userCredential) {
        this.router.navigate(['/home']);
      }
    })
    }

    createUser(user, file) {
      console.log(user);

      if(user.password != user.password_confirmation) {
    let passwordError: any = new Object();
    passwordError["message"] = "Inserted password and inserted password confirmation are different";
    this.eventAuthError.next(passwordError);
      }
      else {
    this.afAuth.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, user.password)
      .then( userCredential => {
        this.newUser = user;
        console.log(userCredential);
        userCredential.user.updateProfile( {
          displayName: user.firstName + ' ' + user.lastName
        });

        this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file).subscribe(downloadURL =>
          this.insertUserData(userCredential, downloadURL)
            .then(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            });
          );
      })
      .catch( error => {
        console.log(error);
        console.log(typeof error);
        this.eventAuthError.next(error);    // Emit the event passing the error object
      });
    }
    }

    uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(fileToBeUploaded) {
      var n = Date.now();
      const filePath = `user_avatar/${n}`;
      const fileRef = this.storage.ref(filePath);

      return this.storage.upload(`user_avatar/${n}`, fileToBeUploaded)
        .snapshotChanges()
        .pipe(switchMap(() => fileRef.getDownloadURL()));

    }

    insertUserData(userCredential: firebase.auth.UserCredential, userAvatar) {

      let userObg = {
        name: this.newUser.firstName,
        surname: this.newUser.lastName,
        complete_name: this.newUser.firstName + " " + this.newUser.lastName,
        email: this.newUser.email,
        role: this.newUser.ruolo_utente,
        avatar: userAvatar
      };

      console.log("USER OBJECT: ", userObg);

      return this.db.doc(`Users/${userCredential.user.uid}`).set(userObg);
    }

    logout() {
      return this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
    }
}
```

My problem is related to the **createUser()** method.

The IDE give me 3 errors on my code (probably because I still have some confusion related to reactive programming style...)

1. On the **this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file)** call it give me the following error message:

> Property 'uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore' does not exist on type
> 'AuthService'.ts(2339)

But as you can see this method is defined into my **AuthService** service class.

2. Similar issue for the **this.insertUserData(userCredential, downloadURL)** cal that give me a simialr error:

> Property 'insertUserData' does not exist on type
> 'AuthService'.ts(2339)

3. Finnally I have an error on this **catch**:

   .catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
   console.log(typeof error);
   this.eventAuthError.next(error);    // Emit the event passing the error object
   });

The IDE says:

> 'try' expected.ts(1005)

But this should take error happens into the **then**

What is wrong with my code? What am I missing? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one `;` too much :)

```
 this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file).subscribe(downloadURL =>
          this.insertUserData(userCredential, downloadURL)
            .then(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            });
          );
```

should be

```
 this.uploadFileIntoFirebaseStore(file).subscribe(downloadURL =>
          this.insertUserData(userCredential, downloadURL)
            .then(() => {
              this.router.navigate(['/home']);
            })
          );
```

Comment: semicolons are facultative in JavaScript

Comment: edit: it was actually a `;` :) I really suggest refactoring some of the code in this function for better readability

Comment: @CristianTraìna Yes, but this one is actually at the end of the `=>` statement, which is incorrect syntax

Comment: Ops, my bad, I thought you had said to add it :)